# Meteor Template.myTemplate.rendered not fired after Accounts.createUser function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I noticed that the `Template.myTemplate.rendered` is not fired after a redirect on `Accounts.createUser` function. If I access the site without the redirect on `Accounts.createUser` the `rendered` function is fired. This is a really strange behaviour.

Here is my code:

```
Accounts.createUser({username: username, password: password}, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                   showErr();
                } else {
                    Router.go('home');
                }
  });

Template.home.rendered = function() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace `showErr()` with `console.log(err)` to be super sure that you log error. Many things can be broken, can you share more code (routes, template, etc ) ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not already on the home template ? Or mabye it is already rendered.

Comment: I don't think that I am already on the home template. Because the `Accounts.createUser` is in `Template.signUp.events`. Maybe it's because the auto login after the account is created. If I do the same thing in `Meteor.loginWithPassword` the home template is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a noob to this and I may be going to far off base here, but is your "else" code firing? In the meteor docs it says called with no arguments on success. So wouldn't it be better to check if "err" exists?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, because of the successful redirection to the `home` template.

Answer (score 0):

I found this package, which solved my problem:

```
 meteor add meteorhacks:fast-render
```

Have a nice day and thank you all for your help!